# Fedora 32 stuck at boot screen with kernel 5.8.4

Tags: fedora, boot, linux-kernel

There is 3 kernel version in my Fedora 32 based desktop: 5.7.15, 5.7.16 and 5.8.4

[image: Multi kernels]

At the time when I was using 5.7.16, I've installed and configured to work with docker, virtualbox and nvidia driver. Everything work well. Then, I upgrade system and get kernel 5.8.4 comes.

Now, it could not boot into kernel 5.8.4, while other kernels still work normally.

[image]

What's the problem? Please give me advise or some keywords for further investigation. Thanks.

The grub file content:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=44ce178f-8763-44a4-8056-d4590d6550a1 rhgb quiet systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

Comment: please add `single` or `emergency` in the kernel line for this new kernel and check if it can boot to `single-mode` or `emergency -mode`. then we can maybe troubleshoot and find the issue. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/

Comment: thank you, I'm not very familiar with grub. The issue seems relate to nvidia driver compatibility. It may get fixed in the next updates.

Answer (score 0):

As I predicted before, the problem has been fixed with the latest update from Nvidia and linux kernel. Today I upgrade the kernel to 5.8.9 then install NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.66, everything works well now.